# Bootstrap container is not working with box-shadow

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use box-shadow effect with bootstrap container. The class is:

```
.effect8
{
position:relative;
box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
.effect8:before, .effect8:after
{
content:"";
position:absolute; 
z-index:-1;
box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
top:10px;
bottom:10px;
left:0;
right:0;
border-radius:100px / 10px;
} 
.effect8:after
{
right:10px; 
left:auto; 
transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
}
```

Whenever I use this class with container-fluid it is working. When I use it with container it is not working. Why?

Comment: can you please put your html as well, or can make a complete code snippet so we can check easily

Comment: Did you tried to add `!important` at the end of the `box-shadow` property?

Comment: its working in both cases.. https://jsfiddle.net/11j5geur/1/ can you post your html?

Comment: Sorry, It is not working with container. Just add container to any div and it is not working.